# arm template functions not working with default values

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment

I am deploying a bunch of resources from Arm template. I am trying to provide the resource name unique by using this `"[uniqueString(subscription().subscriptionId)]"` . I have the templates hosted in github and using the `Deploy to Azure` button am trying to deploy, but the site just shows the plain string with the function and not the value. Any idea would be appreciated.

Between here's my code

```
"parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the function app"
      },
      "defaultValue": "[concat('asfnapp',uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
    }
   }
```

I have the rest of the parameters in the same way.

Edit : Added repository URL - [GITHUB](https://github.com/hariharan618/test)

[image]

Comment: can you add link to the template in GitHub?

Comment: @bmoore-msft i have confidential information in the template

Comment: @bmoore-msft i'll update the question with the template shortly

Comment: @bmoore-msft I have updated the question with the template, please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I thought you were referring to one of the templates in the QuickStart repo - they all (by default) go through this UX: https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template

it looks like you're not using that UX - and I suspect that what you're using does not handle expressions in parameters (just assumes they are strings).  So nothing you can do to fix that (your template is fine).

A workaround would be to use this:

https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fhariharan618%2Ftest%2Fmaster%2Fazuredeploy.json

Comment: Thanks for the reply between , Even in azure portal , the expressions are not handled :( -- > https://imgur.com/a/zGMErrT

Comment: your link worked fine for me...  there are some cases where the portal tries to get "fancy" and validate the value as a string instead of expression (for example if you have a param named "dns*" - but you can work around those by fooling the blade (we're also working on fixing)

Comment: @bmoore-msft: The link is not working anymore and I have the same problem in my environment. Should this be fixed by now?

Comment: What specifically are you seeing?